# Retrieve all data from html table and put in csv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to make a python script to retrieve all my data from the html tables on several pages (I have an array of links)
And I would like this data from the table to be put in a csv.
How can I proceed?
I did something like that but the data is put in without being in columns and rows and is deleted instantly after and the next ones are put.
How can I proceed in the cleanest way possible?
This is table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped product-page-specifications">
                        <tbody><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Product type</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">1</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Tip2</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">MMA
TIG/WIG
</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Material</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Metal </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Size</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Universal </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Color</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Black</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Content</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Material made of a material as resistant as possible</td>
                            </tr></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

This is code:

```
        for a_link in all_links:
            res = requests.get(a_link).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
            table = soup.select_one("table")

            output_rows = []
            for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
              columns = table_row.findAll('td')
              output_row = []
              for column in columns:
                output_row.append(column.text)
                output_rows.append(output_row)

                df = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)
                print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `pd.read_html` works fine on that table, though you may need to do some massaging/merging of things later depending on what the rest of the page looks like and how you want the final output to appear:

```
In [13]: pd.read_html(StringIO(s))
Out[13]:
[              0                                                  1
 0  Product type                                                  1
 1          Tip2                                        MMA TIG/WIG
 2      Material                                              Metal
 3          Size                                          Universal
 4         Color                                              Black
 5       Content  Material made of a material as resistant as po...]
```

In particular, you may want to set that first column as the index and transpose so that you get nicely named columns out of it:

```
In [15]: pd.read_html(StringIO(s))[0].set_index(0).T
Out[15]:
0 Product type         Tip2 Material       Size  Color                                            Content
1            1  MMA TIG/WIG    Metal  Universal  Black  Material made of a material as resistant as po...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for a_link in all_links:
            res = requests.get(a_link).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
            table = soup.select_one("table")
            rows = table.findAll('tr')
            headers = rows[0]
            header_text = []
            for th in headers.findAll('th'):
                header_text.append(th.text)
                row_text_array = []
                for row in rows[1:]:
                    row_text = []
                # loop through the elements
                for row_element in row.findAll(['th', 'td']):
                    # append the array with the elements inner text
                    row_text.append(row_element.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
                # append the text array to the row text array
                row_text_array.append(row_text)
                with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
                    wr = csv.writer(f)
                    wr.writerow(header_text)
                    # loop through each row array
                    for row_text_single in row_text_array:
                        wr.writerow(row_text_single)

                    df = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)
                    print(df)
```

this is full code but in csv don`t show correctly
@Randy